# String input inserted as individual characters

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

Trying to insert users into database using Python through input, whenever I type a name like "kai" it takes each individual letter like "k", "a", "i" instead:

```
cr = db.cursor()

cr.execute("CREATE TABLE if not exists users (user_id int,name text)")
cr.execute("CREATE TABLE if not exists skills (name text,progress int, user_id int )")

question = input("enter your name")

for key, person in enumerate(question):
    cr.execute(f"insert into users(user_id, name) values({key + 1},'{person}')")

db.commit()
db.close()
```

I want entire input as one like "kai", not "k", "a", "i".

Comment: [ask] [mre] https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Comment: Have you ever heard that the first letter in each sentence is almost always capitalized.

Comment: Don't build queries by interpolating user input into strings. https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+injection

Answer (score 0):

A string is an interable. Read [the doc on enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate). When it iterates a string it processes one character at a time, thus the result you see.